# Encapsulating boost::signal and boost::bind

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind, boost-signals

I have a problem now. I am trying to encapsulatie boost::signal and boost::bind into my own Event class.

```
class MyEvent
{
private:
  boost::signal<void ()> Sig;
public:
  void Subscribe(.........)
  {
    Sig.connect(boost:bind(.........);
  }

  void Raise()
  {
    Sig();
  }
};
```

I have try to pass function pointer in the Subscribe function's signature and visual studio just gives me tones of errors.
I dont know how to write the signature of Subscribe and What to pass into boost::bind, ideally I will have `boost::bind(&MyClass::MyHandler, &MyClassObject)` in Subscribe function and will Call it outside like `MyEventObject.Subscribe(&MyClass::MyHandler, &MyClass)`.
Can any people help me fill that two blanks?

Answer (score 0):

You can just make `Subscribe` a template:

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
class MyEvent
{
private:
  boost::signals2::signal<void ()> Sig;
public:
  template<class SlotClass> 
  void Subscribe(void (SlotClass::*func)(), SlotClass *obj)
  {
    Sig.connect(boost::bind(func, obj));
  }
  void Raise()
  {
    Sig();
  }
};

struct Test
{
  void f()
  {}
};

int main()
{
  MyEvent myEvent;
  Test test;
  myEvent.Subscribe(&Test::f, &test); // test must outlive myEvent!
}
```

Note however that such a wrapper limits its user very much: with original `signal` he could connect any `callable` of any kind created in various ways, while with your wrapper he must pass a pointer to member function and a pointer to object.

Comment: Thank you Igor. My boss ask me to encapsulate it so that avoid boost lib everywhere. I really want to expose it as it is more flexible to use boost::signal

Comment: @cynric4sure You mean you're required to eliminate boost from the interfaces? Then, pay attention to the following points: 1) you class still exposes `boost::signals` in its definition (although it's `private`) and thus user's code would depend on boost headers. You might want hide it by means of pImpl; 2) You don't have to limit the user with pointer to member function! Instead, accept any callable and let the user to create it with `std::bind` or what ever he wants.